# Is SSL-strip still viable as a method of attack?

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle, sslstrip

Seeing as SSL-strip works by intercepting redirects and links to HTTPS, is this still a viable MITM attack now that most (all?) up to date browser go for HTTPS by default? Is there an alternative more suitable to a present day scenario?

Comment: I don't know that any browsers go to https by default if you've never been to the website before.  I don't think you can, since it's certainly possible the https: version doesn't even work, or is in a poor state.  Many websites do use HSTS though.  Maybe that's what you're referring to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your base assumption, that all browsers use HTTPS by default, is incorrect.

If you click a link, it uses the protocol specified in the link. The internet is full of HTTP links.

If you enter a URL in the address bar, the browser makes a plain HTTP request first. Trying HTTPS first would not help, since a MITM could just not respond to that request, forcing the browser to try plain HTTP instead.

So yes, SSL-strip is still a very real threat that can not be solved by browsers alone. To fix it, you need HSTS.

Comment: You should mention HSTS preloading, which was designed to mitigate these attacks.